# Can I go to Austria directly from India with Hungarian residence permit?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, india, long-stay-visas, austria

I have a residence permit to stay in Hungary. So I was on holiday in India and now want to go back to Hungary. But I have to attend a concert in Vienna in September so I am thinking of going to Vienna directly from Delhi instead of going to Budapest then to Vienna.

So is it ok  to book flight to Vienna with a residence permit of Hungary? Or do I need to book flight for Budapest from India?

Comment: The suggested duplicate question concerns a type D visa, but the legal effect of such a visa and of a residence permit, for the purpose of the Schengen codes, is the same: they both authorize you to visit other Schengen countries for up to 90 days in any 180-day period.  There have been reports of airlines getting confused about this and denying boarding, but it is most definitely allowed under the Schengen codes.